# How to create slave jenkins given master jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

Below code snippet, taken from [here](https://github.com/jmenga/docker-jenkins/blob/master/Dockerfile#L16) creates master jenkins that runs in a container:

```
# Create Docker Group with GID
# Set default value of 497 if DOCKER_GID set to blank string by Docker Compose
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker

# Used to control Docker and Docker Compose versions installed
# NOTE: As of February 2016, AWS Linux ECS only supports Docker 1.9.1
ARG DOCKER_ENGINE=1.10.2
ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE=1.6.2

# ......

# Install Docker Engine
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D && \
    echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get purge lxc-docker* -y && \
    apt-get install docker-engine=${DOCKER_ENGINE:-1.10.2}-0~trusty -y && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins && \
    usermod -aG users jenkins
```

---

Above container is dind that launches task(each container) on **single** EC2 host.

---

To regulate load across **multiple** EC2 host and launch slave jenkins instance(on each).

We would like to have `master` jenkins generate `build_id` for each build that can run on two slave jenkins instances.

To have master & slave jenkins run within each container, across EC2 hosts.

How to approach on making slave container and take `build_id` from master jenkins?

Comment: Hi there - perhaps it's just me, but I'm having a really hard time understanding what you want to do, reading this this post. The Dockerfile you provided doesn't seem to start anything, just does docker-in-docker.  Do you want to have a multi-master jenkins setup? Do you want multi-cluster agents spawns? Help us understand what you're trying to do please :)

Comment: @BruceBecker a single master Jenkins that has two slave Jenkins. Each jenkins(master and slave)  run on their own  ECS cluster instance

Comment: Thanks! that clarifies things a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) or the [ECS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin) if you want to provision agents dynamically. These would provide some environment variables to use when constructing `build_id` - *e.g.* :

- `BUILD_TAG`:

  > String of "jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}". All forward slashes ("/") in the JOB_NAME are replaced with dashes ("-"). Convenient to put into a resource file, a jar file, etc for easier identification.
- `NODE_NAME`:

  > Name of the agent if the build is on an agent, or "master" if run on master

You would have to configure the clouds in Jenkins, assign a label to the templates you want to use as agents, and then request those in your pipeline or job configuration.

Comment: Does slave jenkins cluster register with ECS service? because master jenkins cluster register with ECS service